# Ember.js Router v2 dynamic slug

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

In the following example, using the new Router v2 API, the ember application behaves as expected with one exception. When hovering over the dynamically created links, using a registered #linkTo Handlebars the url shows undefined.

How do I have a slug field in the URL?

Here is the model

```
App.Todo = DS.Model.extend({
  slug: DS.attr('string'),
  date: DS.attr('date'),
  updated: DS.attr('date'),
  task: DS.attr('string'),
  description: DS.attr('string')
});
```

My Router

```
App.Router.map(function(match){
  this.route('index', {path: '/'});
  this.resource('todos', {path: '/todos'}, function(){
    this.resource('create', {path: '/create'});
    this.resource('todo', {path: '/:slug'}, function(){
      this.resource('edit', {path: 'edit'});
    });
  });
});
```

I know that this does show 'undefined', but this would be a nice (Handlebars)

```
{{#each todo in tasks}}
  <div class="user">
    {{#linkTo todo todo.slug}}<h4><i class="icon-list"></i>{{todo.task}}</h4>{{/linkTo}}
     <p>{{todo.description}}</p>
  </div>
{{/each}}
```

Thanks for any pointers! I'm using Ember-data also

Here is a example fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/R2SPs/6/

Answer (score 4):

This works for ember routing v2.1 (01.16.13)

Thanks to rakl on #emberjs on IRC here is a mixin that solves the problem

```
   App.SlugRouter = Ember.Mixin.create({
        serialize: function(model, params) {
            var name, object;
            object = {};
            name = params[0];
            object[name] = model.get('slug');
            return object;
        }
    });
```

Now just place that in your Router and your golden

```
App.TodoRoute = Ember.Route.extend(App.SlugRouter,{
    //insert your code
});
```

Comment: Next to explaining how to fix it, it would be nice to know why this fixes it.

Comment: Pretty sure this fixed it: ```model: function(params) { return this.store.find("post", {slug: params.post_slug});}```, where ``post_slug`` refers to the identifier used in your ``router.js``

Answer (score 0):

The path of the route is "todo.index" with the resource definition:

```
this.resource('todo', {path: '/:slug'}, ...
```

So create Route and Controller for it.

Comment: That does not answer the question I'm having -> this fiddle should act as proof. http://jsfiddle.net/R2SPs/8/